# Finding a non- trivial group G such that G is isomorphic to G* G

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The question is to find a nontrivial group $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $G\times G$.
I cannot find any. First of all if the group is finite then only trivial group is the possible one. So the group cannot be finite. So we need to find among infinite groups. Will anybody please help me in this case.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean direct product or free product?

Comment: Direct product .....

Comment: Somewhat famously the reals (with addition) are isomorphic to the complex plane (again with addition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ (They have both an uncountable basis of the same cardinality) so their additive groups are isomorphic.